# A simple Python IRC client library that supports SSL?

Tags: python, irc

A simple Python IRC client library that supports SSL?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com/trac/wiki/TwistedWords) has an IRC client (in twisted.words), and it supports SSL.

There is an [example in the documentation](http://twistedmatrix.com/projects/words/documentation/examples/ircLogBot.py), just remember to do `reactor.connectSSL` instead of `reactor.connectTCP`.

If you don't want Twisted, there is also the [Python IRC library](http://python-irclib.sourceforge.net/), which I notice has SSL support in the latest release.

Answer (score 0):

How simple? Chatzilla supports SSL and as any Mozilla Platform applications, allows using Python. https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Python

On second thought, that probably is a total overkill. A second on Ali's answer, Twisted will do.

Answer (score 0):

irc3 support ssl (via asyncio) https://irc3.readthedocs.org/